# Replace categorical values in CSV file with binary values

Tags: python, csv, replace

I have a  clinical data set and I have to replace

- the 1st column values 'DECEASED' with 1, if the value 'Date' > 365 else replace with 0 (zero),
- the value  'LIVING' with one if 'Day_to_follow_up' > 365

In addition I need to assign the ages

- 0-25     to bin 0,
- 25-50    to bin 1,
- 50-75    to bin 2
- above 75 to bin 4.

Here is my code.

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
with open('combined_file', 'rb') as f,open('newFile', 'wb') as out:
    reader = csv.reader(f)


    writer = csv.writer(out)
    for row in reader:
        #print "AABB"
        if 'DECEASED' in row[1]:
            if row[10]>365:
                row[1]=1
                writer.writerow(row)
            elif row[10]<365:
                row[1]=0
                writer.writerow(row)
        if 'LIVING' in row[1]:
            if row[11]>365:
                row[1]=1
                writer.writerow(row)
```

sample input

```
sample id , status , age ,gender ,date ,days_to_last_followup
0     ,    Deceased , 42 , M  ,   326 ,    149
1     ,    Deceased , 56 , F  ,   500 ,    30
2     ,    living   , 43 ,M   ,   25  ,    150
```

sample output

```
sample id , status , age ,gender,date ,days_to_last_followup
0     ,       0    , 1 ,  M    ,326 ,    149
1     ,       1    , 2 , F     ,500 ,    30
2     ,       0    , 1 ,M   ,   25  ,    150
```

Comment: You imported pandas. Drop `import csv` and use `df = pd.read_csv("input.csv"); ... ; pdf.to_csv("out.csv")` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your question is, based off this post.  Either way, the logical structure would have an issue if both 'Deceased' and 'Living' were in row[1].  I'd suggest you create some test cases to look for bad data, since ETL processes routinely have to deal with unexpected data formats/fields.

I'm also not sure why you are importing the pandas library.  You don't seem to be calling it anywhere in the code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a good starting point - a few things that the code does not cover:

- What happens when 'DECEASED' and 'LIVING' are both in `row[1]`? Your code will write two rows. To fix this, set the `if 'LIVING'` to `elif 'LIVING'`.
- You need an `else` case to catch what happens when neither `DECEASED` or `LIVING` is in `row[1]`.